# Capture card as external monitor

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a notebook and a PC. I would like to connect my notebook to my PC and watch my notebook's screen on a software on my PC. I figured out that I might could use a capture card for this. My idea is to buy a capture card, connect it to my PC, and connect my notebook to the capture card via a HDMI cable. After this, will I be able to use a software on my PC as an external monitor for my notebook? Or are there any better solution for this?

The capture card that I would buy:

[Mini USB 3.0 HD 1080P 60Hz HDMI to USB Video Capture Card Game Recording Box - Banggood](https://www.banggood.com/Mini-USB-3_0-HD-1080P-60Hz-HDMI-to-USB-Video-Capture-Card-Game-Recording-Box-for-Youtube-Live-Streaming-Broadcast-Game-Recording-p-1727292.html)

Comment: Seems a bit of a long way round, when there's Remote Desktop. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I cannot use any software for this on my notebook, because I have no admin rights to install any software on it. It is a laptop for work.

Comment: What do you want to do on your work notebook while it's connected to your PC?

Comment: I have a KVM switch so I can control it from the same keyboard/mouse that I use for my PC as well. I just use it for internal chat software and emails, and I want to do t on my main screen without plugging it into the monitor (because i constantly switch between the screens, sometimes i just check if i have a new email or not, etc.

Comment: I think your idea would work, but you may have some resolution issues from the capture card, depending on the laptop output resolution and your PC monitor resolution. You may be able to mitigate them through scaling or using a smaller resolution output from you laptop. If you're using a KVM to control your laptop and your PC, you may want to mind where the video to your PC monitor is coming from when your KVM is switched to your laptop. You could potentially just use the KVM to switch your mouse and keyboard between the laptop and PC, and keep your PC video connected directly to your monitor.

Comment: Resolution issues are not a big problem for me since I only use the notebook for emails and chat. Thanks, I ordered it yesterday, hope it will work. If not, I will use the capture card for turning my camera to webcam. :)

Comment: @paquantems375 , I don't know whether this device comes with it's own recording software or not, but you can use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/index.html) freeware to display the source of the recording device.  You wouldn't even need to have it recording, just set it to stream the recording and leave it on standby (paused).  It should still display the device output while not filling up your drive with recording you don't need.

Comment: Got you, I already read articles about VLC. Thank you! :)